# how to parse XML in SAX parser, with tags with in data?

Tags: xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I have a XML with the following structure

```
<abstract>
<p>
This is just a dummy <italic> abstract</italic>. That<italic> is giving</italic> problem
</p>
</abstract>
```

I want to parse this xml in SAX. I have written the parser but in endElement function for tag

```
</p>
```

i only get "problem" instead of the whole data with in the tag.
Is there a way to parse this with SAX parser in Java ?

Comment: Show us what the result should look like, and the code you've tried.  Yes, this can be parsed with SAX, but not without knowing what the result is supposed to be.

Comment: This looks more like HTML than XML. Yes it can be done with SAX, but you may want to try an HTML parser instead.

Comment: I am parsing Plos One Xml. In the abstract there are some tags that shouldnt be there in an Xml. Is it possible to parse such Xml.

http://www.plosone.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action;jsessionid=67E7C9846AA98367CD8CDAF11CB72A9D?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0039136&representation=XML